# Webpack and React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I try to use webpack with my react.js-application. The issue I am having is regarding the images. If I require the correct image in my entry-file, the image gets build to the correct destination, but my application can't find it. I just get a blank image:

```
main.jsx: require('./styles/images/logo.png');

in my application: <img src="images/logo.png"  width="60%" alt="" />
```

When I require the image directly in the src-tag however everything is good:

```
<img src={require('../styles/images/logo.png')} alt="" width="80px" />
```

Is there anyone know what I am doing wrong? I would like to be able to just require the whole image-folder and every img-tag would be filled with the correct image. Any leads toward the solution would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that the loader is correctly set in the webpack configuration, you would usually import and use an image in the following way:

```
var image = require('./styles/images/logo.png');
```

And then:

```
<img src={image} />
```

The two statements must obviously reside in the same file.

Comment: Yes, thats basically how I am doing it now. So this is the best practice when it comes to webpack and images? To require the images I need in each file instead of requiring all the images in my entry-file?